# TFS: Projects, Portfolio Management, and Source Code

Tags: tfs, portfolio-management

I'm exploring using TFS for Portfolio Management, and it seems generally suggested to lump all teams, features, etc. into a single project to provide executives an enterprise-wide view of the work going on.

However, in moving to a single project, we would lose some flexibility with source control. We would like to be able to wall off developers, and ensure they only work on certain applications (for instance, we might have external developers that only have permission to work on a specific application).

Is there any guidance on how organizations are using TFS for both Portfolio Management and Source Control simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you lose in a [single Team Project](https://nkdagility.com/blog/one-team-project/)?

You are either using TFVC which allows you to secure at the folder level, and remove inheritance for greater control.

Or you are using Git which is secured at the Repository level.

Either way you can control which groups of users have access to which code. You can have view only access for some code, and write access for other, or no access at all within the same Team Project.

See also [Many Git Repositories, but one Team Project to rule them all](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/willy-peter_schaub/many-git-repositories-but-one-team-project-to-rule-them-all).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.